# How to configure Identity Server 2.0.1 (Sitecore 9.1.1) to use Active Directory?

Tags: identity-server

Has anyone successfully configured Identity Server 2.0.1 (SC 9.1.1) to use Active Directory?  The only official documentation and examples I have seen are with Azure AD (not regular on prem AD).  I found this very good blog post (https://sitecore.derekc.net/setting-up-azure-active-directory-integration-with-sitecore-identity-server-sitecore-9-1/) but that is for Azure AD.

It seems odd to me that Sitecore would not provide out of the box support with examples for regular Active Directory.  Unless I am missing something and it is simple to set up for regular AD.

Comment: AD requires creating a subprovider with Sitecore IDs

Answer (score 2):

Sitecore 9.1.0 and later uses Identity server and Owin authentication, so Active Directory module is officially not supported. **You need to set up the Federated Authentication**.

Refer the [Sitecore document](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-management/en/using-federated-authentication-with-sitecore.html) where they mentioned the same and also there are steps to setup the Federated Authentication.